# How to select dynamically created elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

I'm updating some elements dynamically based on user-input. Specifically, I have a table of form fields which the user can fill in. When the page loads I can count how many are empty...

```
$(whocares).click(callback);

callback = function() {
    var empties = $('.something input[value=""]);
    var count = empties.length; //4
}
```

but after the user fills in new ones, the count stays the same.

When I inspect the DOM, I don't see the updated values either. The new form fields still say: `value` instead of `value="whatever"`.

All the jQuery is inside `$(document).ready();`

How do I get jQuery to see the new changes?

Comment: You would have to do `$('.something input[value^=""]).length;` everytime to get the count.

Comment: @imtheman I am doing exactly this, inside the callback of a click event.

Comment: Oh I see. Try `var empties = $('.something input[value=""]);` instead.

Comment: @imtheman ...unless I misunderstood and you're saying I need to do it in one line rather than two, as show in my question.

Comment: No, sorry. You need to remove the `^` from the `input[value^=""]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of jQuery 1.9, the [value=] notation in selectors, only deals with attributes (.attr) and these attributes do not match the current state of form elements, but the 'value' attribute of the element.

Only the property (.prop) of the form element will map the current value of this element.

you can get the empty elements via

```
$(":input").filter(function () { return $(this).val() === ""; });
```

you can read the [jQuery 1.9 upgrade guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#attr-versus-prop-) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
var count = 0;
$('.something input').each(function()
    if($(this).val().length = 0) {
        count++;
    }
});
```

Comment: I'll try it. Do you mind explaining why iterating with `.each` should work but not a straight `$(x)` selection?

Comment: I'm using each because input[value=""] is a css selector. If you enter a value on a input it doesn't change the html value attribute. When using each you check every element dynamically for the value

Answer (score 2):

First thing is to know that when you run a jQuery selector you're asking it to look at the *current* state of the DOM and find the elements that match your selector.  When you set a variable to equal the result of that jQuery function, you end up with an array of jQuery elements which represent the DOM elements that were matched.  When accessing that cached variable you *do not* ask the DOM again for matching elements.

So for example:

```
var empties = $('.something input[value^=""]');
empties.length // 4;
```

If the DOM then changes state, IE: you put some values in two of the input fields, `empties.length` remains 4 because it's just a cache of the previous selection - it's not doing the selection again.  In order to check to see how many empties there are now, you need to do the selection again `$('.something input[value^=""]').length` would now equal 2.

So the solution here is not to cache the result of the selection in `empties` but to just call `$('.something input[value^=""]').length` directly and it'll give you the number of matches to that selector (the number of empties in this example) straight from the DOM every time it's run.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I updated the question to better demonstrate what I'm doing. The var in question is inside a callback, so I *think* I'm already doing what you propose and it's not working.

Comment: Ah okay, in which case it's probably an issue with the selector.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```
$(document).on("change", "youtInput.YourImputClass", function(){
  var count = $(document).find("youtInput.YourImputClass[value^='']").length;
}
```

That should do the trick.

Hope this will be helpfull.
Good luck.